# Using GCD for back ground processing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I am working on app having db sync mechanism.

I was calling the sync service as follows

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(sync) 
                         toTarget:[SyncService sharedInstance] 
                       withObject:nil];
```

But the problem here is , the sync is not performed in background. As a result application

will be idle until the sync is complete. So, I thought of using GCD for background

processing and did the following

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

    [[SyncService sharedInstance]Sync]; 

});
```

But even now the sync is not performed in the background.I want the sync to be performed in

background.

EDIT:

Whenever I dont use [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(sync)

```
                                toTarget:[SyncService sharedInstance] withObject:nil];,
```

the immediate next line [[[SyncService sharedInstance] delegate]addObject:self]; is not

called . This is not called when I use GCD(global queue).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `dispatch_get_global_queue` method with the wrong properties, the first 0 means `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` or any other of the priority predefined:
`DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH`, `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT`, `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW` or `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND`.
.

You should call it like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [[SyncService sharedInstance]Sync]; 
});
```

---

Also the documentation states that calling [`+detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/detachNewThreadSelector%3atoTarget%3awithObject%3a) will start a new thread. Are you sure that nothing else is blocking the UI. and what do you do in the `sync` methods do you call the main thread? This could mean that the main thread/queue will block again.

Comment: No I am not calling the main thread in Sync , still something is blocking

Comment: @rckoenes `dispatch_get_global_queue()` returns a background queue for every queue priority type. Check the docs. Background priority simply means that it has the lowest priority. Something is going on in his singleton, I would suspect.

Comment: Then its not the method called `Sync` that is blocking your UI.

Comment: Finally I found that , my sync was not entering the background coz I was using MBprogressHud, which i downloaded from net. I think its doing something that block  the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
[[SyncService sharedInstance] performSelectorInBackground:@selector(Sync) withObject:nil]
```

As rckoenes says you should be sure that nothing is done on the main thread in your Sync method